# Drop down menu location select widget

Tags: plugins, menus

This code select menu by names but i want to do it selecting registered menu location.below is my exact code.

```
  class MyWidget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'description' => __('Use this widget to add one of your custom menu as a link list widget.') );
        parent::__construct( 'custom_menu_widget-1', __('My name'), $widget_ops );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        // Get menu
        $nav_menu = ! empty( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object( $instance['nav_menu'] ) : false;

        if ( !$nav_menu )
            return;

        $instance['title'] = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );



        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( !empty($instance['title']) )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $instance['title'] . $args['after_title'];

        wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $nav_menu) );

        echo $args['after_widget'];

    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['title']) );
        $instance['nav_menu'] = (int) $new_instance['nav_menu'];
        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        $nav_menu = isset( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? $instance['nav_menu'] : '';

        // Get menus
        $menus = get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

        // If no menus exists, direct the user to go and create some.
        if ( !$menus ) {
            echo '<p>'. sprintf( __('No menus have been created yet. <a href="%s">Create some</a>.'), admin_url('nav-menus.php') ) .'</p>';
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:') ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nav_menu'); ?>"><?php _e('Select Menu:'); ?></label>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nav_menu'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('nav_menu'); ?>">
        <?php
            foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
                $selected = $nav_menu == $menu->term_id ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                echo '<option'. $selected .' value="'. $menu->term_id .'">'. $menu->name .'</option>';
            }
        ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );

function myplugin_register_widgets() {

      register_widget( 'MyWidget' );

}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using `get_nav_menu_locations()` in conjunction with `wp_get_nav_menu_object()`?

Comment: Did not work!!!

Comment: How is that reply of any use to anybody on this site trying to help you out, barring the fact that it was incredibly rude. Those functions are the ones you will need to use to get your idea working. So how about you show us what you did and explain why it didn't work. For good measure you could try being grateful for the help.